# Problem in ARIMA Model in R

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am running ARIMA model in R and I used auto.arima(X) function to decide appropriate model.After using this function I found that the order of my model is ARIMA(2,1,0).
The problem is I run the same ARIMA(2,1,0) model using arima(X,order=c(2,1,0)) and I got AIC as AIC=832.16. but for same model by using auto.arima(X) as AIC=805.29. I dont know why for the same model AIC is different. Please hep me to over come this problem.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please, give further details of what you are doing. Are you using the default options for these functions?. Posting the data (the output from `dput(series.name)`) will help as well.

In the example below I get the same AIC ($330.97$) for model ARIMA(2,1,0) with `forecast::auto.arima` and `stats::arima`:

```
require(forecast)
set.seed(127)
x <- arima.sim(n=120, model=list(order=c(2,1,0), ar=c(0.7,-0.3)))
forecast::auto.arima(x)
# Series: x 
# ARIMA(2,1,0)                    
# Coefficients:
#          ar1      ar2
#       0.8619  -0.4422
# s.e.  0.0820   0.0816
# sigma^2 estimated as 0.8719:  log likelihood=-162.48
# AIC=330.97   AICc=331.17   BIC=339.33
stats::arima(x, order=c(2,1,0))
# Series: x 
#ARIMA(2,1,0)                    
#Coefficients:
#         ar1      ar2
#      0.8619  -0.4422
#s.e.  0.0820   0.0816
#sigma^2 estimated as 0.8719:  log likelihood=-162.48
#AIC=330.97   AICc=331.17   BIC=339.33
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a model i use to forecast with ARIMA which i find to be much better than auto arima:

```
N<-c(#Input your data#)
deltaT<-~set observations per year, 1/4 for quarterly, 1/12 for monthly
horiz<-#set the amount of forecasts you want to do
startY<-c(#,#) #set the start date c(8,1) for 2008 quarter 1 etc
force.log <- "log" # takes values "s" (lets script choose logging) "level" (forces levels) or "log" (forces logs)
Nu <- ts(N, deltat=deltaT, start = startY)
NbMAT <- matrix(0, ncol= (1/deltaT), nrow = (length(Nu)+(1/deltaT)), byrow=TRUE)
for (i in 1:(1/deltaT)) 
{NbMAT[,i] <- c(rep(0, length = i-1), lag(Nu, k=-i+1), rep(0, length = (1/deltaT)-i+1))}
Nbind <- NbMAT[c(-1:(-(1/deltaT)+1), -(length(NbMAT[,1])-1/deltaT+1):-(length(NbMAT[,1]))),]
Nbind2 <- data.frame(Nbind)
lm1 <- lm(X1 ~., data=Nbind2)
lm2 <- lm(X1 ~ X2 + Nbind2[, length(Nbind2[1,])], data=Nbind2)
library(lmtest)
library(car)
bptest1 <- bptest(lm1)
bptest2 <- bptest(lm2) 
gqtest1 <- gqtest(lm1)
if (force.log == "level") {aslog <- "n"} else {{if (force.log == "log") {aslog <- "y"} else {if (bptest1$p.value < 0.1 | bptest2$p.value < 0.1 | gqtest1$p.value < 0.1) {aslog <- "y"} else {aslog <- "n" }}}}
    if(aslog == "y") {N <- log(Nu)} else {N <- Nu}
    plot(N)
    pacf(N)
    cat("log series, y/n? : ", aslog)
    library(tseries)
    library(forecast)
    max.sdiff <- 3 # set maximum seasonal differences allowed. For typical series, 0 is fine.
    arima.force.seasonality <- "n"
    kpssW <- kpss.test(N, null="Level")
    # alt ndiffs(N, alpha = 0.05, test = "kpss") #or test ="adf" / "pp"
    ppW <- tryCatch({ppW <- pp.test(N, alternative = "stationary")},  error = function(ppW) {ppW <- list(error = "TRUE", p.value = 0.99)})
    # if > 0.05, assume unit root. Automated error catching throws in unit root if pp test matrix is singular
    adfW <- adf.test(N, alternative = "stationary", k = trunc((length(N)-1)^(1/3)))
    if(kpssW$p.value < 0.05 | ppW$p.value > 0.05 | adfW$p.value > 0.05) {ndiffsW = 1} else {ndiffsW = 0}
aaw <- auto.arima(N, max.D= max.sdiff, d=ndiffsW, seasonal=TRUE, 
              allowdrift=FALSE, stepwise=FALSE, trace=TRUE, seasonal.test="ch")
orderWA <- c(aaw$arma[1], aaw$arma[6] , aaw$arma[2])
    orderWS <- c(aaw$arma[3], aaw$arma[7] , aaw$arma[4])
if(sum(aaw$arma[1:2])==0) {orderWA[1] <- 1} else {NULL}
    if(arima.force.seasonality == "y") {if(sum(aaw$arma[3:4])==0) {orderWS[1] <- 1} else {NULL}} else {NULL}
    Arimab <- Arima(N, order= orderWA, seasonal=list(order=orderWS), method="ML")
    fArimab <- forecast(Arimab, h=8, simulate= TRUE, fan=TRUE)
    if (aslog == "y") {fArimabF <- exp(fArimab$mean[1:horiz])} else {fArimabF <-fArimab$mean[1:horiz]}
    # View(fArimabF, title = "Arima forecast") # gives the forecast
    plot(fArimab, main = "ARIMA Forecast", sub="blue=fitted, red=actual") # ylim=c(17, 20)
    lines(N, col="red", lwd=2)
    lines(ts(append(fitted(Arimab), fArimab$mean[1]), deltat=deltaT, start = startY), 
  col= "blue", lwd = 2) # makes the graph look nicer
if (aslog == "y") {Arimab2f <- exp(fArimab$mean[1:horiz])} else {Arimab2f <- fArimab$mean[1:horiz]}
    start(fArimab$mean) -> startARIMA
ArimaALTf <- ts(prettyNum(Arimab2f, big.interval = 3L, big.mark = ","), deltat = deltaT , start= startARIMA)
View(ArimaALTf, title = "ARIMA forecast")
summary(Arimab)
```